# How do I log nan/inf in log metrics on Vertex AI aiplatform.log_metrics?

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

Trying to log nan/inf as they are intrinsic to our data types. Need to log them, but can't find a way how.

Answer (score 0):

Found this: currently we support logging str in log_metrics. So users can log nan/inf values by aiplatform.log_metrics({'key_1':'n/a', 'key_2':'inf').

You can see it in the [library reference doc](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/aiplatform/latest/google.cloud.aiplatform.ExperimentRun#google_cloud_aiplatform_ExperimentRun_log_metrics), or check the method detail in your IDE by:

from google.cloud import aiplatform
aiplatform.log_metrics?